# haskell adding two CNFs

Tags: haskell, logic

for my programming I implemented following structure:

```
data Logic a = Empty
              |And     (Logic a) (Logic a)
              | Or      (Logic a) (Logic a)
              | Equal   (AtomVariable a) (AtomVariable a)
              | Not (Logic a) 
              deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

I will have CNF's of Equals or Not(Equal)s. My goal is to add one CNF to another and modify the result if neccesary. E.g. if I have (a=b OR a=c) AND (c!=b) and I want to add (a!=b) the result should be a=c AND c!=b AND a!=b
I managed to do this for one equation (adding a=b or a!=b to a logic):

```
check :: Eq a => Logic a -> Logic a -> Bool
check (Equal a b) (Equal c d)
    | a == c && b == d = False
    | a == d && b == c = False
    | otherwise = True

check (Equal a b) (Not (Equal c d)) 
    | a == c && b == d = False
    | a == d && b == c = False
    | otherwise = True

check (Equal a b) (Or c d) = ((check (Equal a b) c) || (check (Equal a b) d))

check (Equal a b) (And c d) = ((check (Equal a b) c) && (check (Equal a b) d))

check (Equal a b) (Implication c d e)  = check (Equal a b) (And (Equal c d) (Not (Equal c e)))

check1 :: Eq a => Logic a -> Logic a -> Bool
check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (Equal c d) 
    | a == c && b == d = False
    | a == d && b == c = False
    | otherwise = True

check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (Not (Equal c d)) 
    | (check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (Equal c d)) == False = False
    | otherwise = True

check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (Or c d) = ((check1 (Not (Equal a b)) c) || (check1 (Not (Equal a b)) d))

check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (And c d) = ((check1 (Not (Equal a b)) c) && (check1 (Not (Equal a b)) d))

check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (Implication c d e)  = check1 (Not (Equal a b)) (And (Equal c d) (Not (Equal c e)))

add1 :: Eq a => Logic a -> Logic a -> Logic a
add1 (Equal a b) logic
    | check (Equal a b) logic == True = And logic (Equal a b)
    | otherwise = logic


add1 (Not (Equal a b)) logic
    | (check1 (Not (Equal a b)) logic) == True = And logic (Equal a b)
    | otherwise = logic
```

I guess it is not the best way to do it, but I further want to add a whole logic to another.

Comment: Your data type can hold much more complicated expressions than just those in CNF. If you want to work with CNF exclusively, you should trim down your data type so that it can only represent CNF expressions. That will make all of the simplification rules easier.

Comment: Yes I only need the CNF. But I thought it is already as simply as possible. How should I do that?

Comment: From wikipedia: "[a CNF is] a conjunction of one or more clauses, where a clause is a disjunction of literals":  so, how about: `newtype CNF = Conjunction [ Clause ] ; newtype Clause = Disjunction [ Literal ] ; type Literal = Bool`. We can do this without even understanding the problem domain. Note this isn't quite correct since I think we'd like both lists to be *nonempty*. There are non-empty list libraries on hackage, or you could roll something yourself or structure things differently, but holding to this same general shape.

Comment: @jberryman Bool doesn't seem like a good base type for a CNF expression. You probably want a symbol of some kind, to represent a variable, eg `newtype Var = Var String`. And the lists being empty or not doesn't really matter: there are reasonable interpretations of a conjunction  or disjunction of zero clauses.

Comment: The thing is I don't have bool values I only have equations. And even if I could simplify my logic, how should I do what I asked for (add one logic to another)?